# Minecraft ComputerCraft mod MiningTurtle starts wrong OS

Tags: minecraft, minecraft-forge, computercraft

I found a similar question being asked here, but the answer has been moved to ether apparently.

http://www.computercraft.info/forums2/index.php?/topic/20148-turtle-os-not-showing-up-on-new-install/

My son loves Minecraft, and I want to get him more interested in programming, so I tried downloading the ComputerCraft Mod (I'm a complete Minecraft noob).

I installed ComputerCraft on Minecraft 1.8.9 Java Edition Mac OS X, and have gotten Turtles to show up in my inventory.  I can place a mining turtle and use it, but when I do, I see that it is running "CraftOS" and not "TurtleOS".  When I try to run `turtle.turnLeft()` - I get a `true` value returned, and the turtle indeed turns around, but I do not see the animation of it turning around - just at its final location when I exit the command prompt.

I'm at a loss.  Can someone help?

Answer (score 1):

Everything workd fine. In older versions, the os showed Turtle OS instaead of Craft OS when it was running on a turtle, but it was still the same os. In never versions CraftOS is showed on Computers and Turtles. There is no spefic TurtleOS.

Comment: Thanks - yes I also found that written in some documentation I just found.  Do you have any idea why the animation when the turtle is commanded to turn left isn't showing as it does here:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DSsx4VSe-Uk&t=333s  at around 5:40?  Is this now obsolete behavior that went away with turtleOS, when it was called that?  In my case, I just see the turtle in the new orientation as soon as I hide the command window.

Comment: Same goes for things like turtle.back().  I can see it move if it stops being occluded by the command window.  Can I get it to do movement after I close window?

Comment: The turtle is turned when you execute the command. It will not wait for closing the window and theren is no possibility to do this.

Comment: Thank you Jakob.  On closer look, in the video the guy was probably closing the command window really quick, making it seem like the turtle only started moving after the window was closed.